# nodejs express 3.0 app.use does it get called

Tags: node.js, express

I am using *Express 3.x* and when I put

```
express = require("express")
routes = require("./routes")
http = require("http")
path = require("path")
app = express()
app.configure ->
    app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 3000
    app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
    app.set "view engine", "jade"
    app.use express.favicon()
    app.use express.logger("dev")
    app.use express.bodyParser()
    app.use express.methodOverride()
    app.use app.router
    app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))

app.use (req,res,next)->
    res.locals.name = "Jesse"
    next()


app.use "/", (req,res,next)->
    res.locals.name = "Jesse"

app.configure "development", ->
    app.use express.errorHandler()

app.get "/", routes.index

http.createServer(app).listen app.get("port"), ->
    console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get("port")
```

and my *View* is

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p Hello Mr #{name}
```

I am expecting the first middleware(app.use) to get called every time the get request comes in, but it doesn't happen.  Is there any change from express2.x?

This is from the express 3.x directory and it is commented

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/view-locals/index.js

Thanks

Comment: 1) your indentation is off 2) you're probably calling `app.router` or `app[VERB]` before any of those two `app.use`

Comment: identation is off here...not in the code..& I am calling app.use before the app.get

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how it should look. you have to place the middleware above `app.router`

```
express = require("express")
routes = require("./routes")
http = require("http")
path = require("path")
app = express()
app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 3000
app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
app.set "view engine", "jade"
app.use express.favicon()
app.use express.logger("dev")
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()

app.use (req,res,next)->
    res.locals.name = "Jesse"
    next()

app.use app.router
app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))

app.configure "development", ->
    app.use express.errorHandler()

app.get "/", routes.index

http.createServer(app).listen app.get("port"), ->
    console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get("port")
```

Comment: i couldn't find this anywhere in the documentation. did you also find this by trial and error?

Answer (score 3):

You can try running your script using the DEBUG flag to see what is going on.  Express has debug statements that show which routes have been defined and how requests are being handled.

```
$ DEBUG=* node app.js
```

Comment: if stylus spams you, its `DEBUG=express:*,connect:*`

Comment: actually, see the [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) module for more on how to use it. `DEBUG=*,-stylus:*` will leave out all stylus but keep everything else, not just express and connect

Answer (score 1):

Move the app.use to the top...and it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your middleware above the **app.configure()** section.

Comment: nope. I tried that..more weirdo ..if you use res.locals.name it would not get passed to the view !!! there is something about name the locals doesn't like you can use res.local.fname or any other variable